# Check for numeric value into input field using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to make sure that users enter only numeric value into the input field.  I tried the following but its not working. **Don't want to set attribute like  `onkeypress="return isNumeric(event, value)` manually."**

```js
// Event listeners
saleForm.querySelectorAll('input.only_numeric').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('keypress', isNumeric);
});

// Functions
function isNumeric(event) {
    const value = this.value;
    const unicode = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;

    if (value.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        if (unicode == 46) return false;
    }

    if (unicode != 46) {
        if ((unicode < 48 || unicode > 57) && unicode != 46) return false;
    }
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="bill-cust-mobile" tabindex="4" class="only_numeric">
```

Comment: input type="number" ?

Comment: [Perhaps search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+input+numeric+only+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

Set: `<input type="number">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional with  operation `number%1`

Example:

```
function isNumeric(event) {
    const value = this.value;
    const unicode = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
    
    return !isNaN(value) && value % 1 == 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. excellent observation!

Answer (score 0):

Try also isNan:

```
//Runs code if val is numeric
if(!isNan(val){...}
```